# How to attach gradle-api sources in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I'm working on a custom Gradle plugin. For some reason IntelliJ is unable to find the sources of the `gradle-api` artifact and only shows the decompiled .class file. I am already using the `-all` distribution of the Gradle Wrapper (which includes *some* sources, but apparently not the ones I need right here). Clicking **Download...** results in an error:

```
Sources not found: Sources for 'gradle-api-6.5.1.jar' not found
```

How do I correctly attach/choose sources for `gradle-api` in IntelliJ?

[image: IntelliJ]

EDIT:

I have a minimal Gradle plugin with code like that (taken from the [official samples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_gradle_plugin.html)):

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

gradlePlugin {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How do you define the dependency in your project? The sources are available at https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/org/gradle/gradle-core-api/5.6.1/. Did you add this repository in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - That brought me a little closer. First I had to downgrade to Gradle 6.1.1 (somehow that's the last published version with the link you posted). Then it was possible to _manually_ attach the download sources jar file. Automatic download still does not work, even after adding a custom repository to the build script.

Comment: How do you declare this dependency in build script? Do you have gradle composite build? Do you use Groovy DSL?

Comment: Looks like [IDEA-221322](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221322), [IDEA-197970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197970).

Comment: Thanks @Andrey - It does indeed look like it's related to those tickets.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Do you happen to know if/where Gradle releases _after_ 6.1.1 are published? repo.gradle.org, as well as mvnrepository, etc appear to only contain versions <= 6.1.1

Answer (score 2):

According to [this excellent manual](https://github.com/croz-ltd/klokwrk-project/blob/master/support/documentation/article/debugging-gradle-from-idea/debugging-gradle-from-idea.md) you should add `gradleApi()` as a `runtimeOnly` dependency:

```
dependencies {
   //...
   runtimeOnly(gradleApi())
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that, the default Intellij config `use gradle from gradle-wrapper.properties file` will use `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, but it doesn't contain source code. what you need is a jar like `gradle-wrapper-all.jar`. But I don't know how to let Gradle redownload that. Just setting `Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL` is not working.

### Solution

1. set `Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL`

```
wrapper {
    jarFile = file(System.getProperty("user.dir") + '/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    gradleVersion = '6.7.1'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

2. **I download Gradle, and use it**. Set two things here and refresh it.

[image]

Here is the source code, the version is right and with `all` in the name (`gradle-6.7.1-all`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. delete gradle dir
2. run "gradle wrapper"
3. check the suffix "-all" in the file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
   sample:
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.